# How to set text style normal and hint style bold in Text Input Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k4pi.png)

Same like this i need but i can't found anywhere.

Comment: pls suggest if any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: what is the problem? just read the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md). It's very simple to change the text and hint style.

Comment: Check the `app:hintTextAppearance` attribute

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="E-Mail Address" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```